# Counting occurrences in strings and formatting strings: Displaying results

Tags: javascript, html, string

For my lab assignment, one part of the exercise asks me to add a function to an already existing string that counts the number of occurrences of a specific character in a string, and returns the count.

Here's the function:

```
var string;
var i;
var count=0;

string="Jose lived in San Jose for many years";

string.prototype.countOccurrences = function countOccurrences(thechar){
for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    if(this.charAt(i) == thechar){
        count++;
        }
    }
return count;
}
```

The problem I'm having with the exercise is displaying the result. I'm trying to count and display the occurrences of the letter 'e' in the string. This is what I've been using but it makes the rest of the program disappear when I run it.

```
document.write("There are " + string.countOccurrences("e") + "e's in this string");
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have `string` as a variable. Therefore, setting a method of the prototype won't do anything. You need to set it on the `String` class.

```
String.prototype.countOccurrences = function( thechar ) {
    var i;
    var count=0;
    for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
        if(this.charAt(i) == thechar){
            count++;
         }
    }
    return count;
};

var string = "Jose lived in San Jose for many years";
document.write("There are " +string.countOccurrences("e")+ "e's in this string");
```

Comment: William, I tried changing the capitalization of the class for the prototype as you did, but I seem to be getting the same result when running the program, with nothing showing up.

Comment: `===` instead of `==`. You don't want to enable type coercion.

Comment: Put the function declaration above the variable. It should work. If it doesn't, you might have an error somewhere else in your code. [http://jsfiddle.net/6W4LS/](http://jsfiddle.net/williamvanr/6W4LS/)